# Changing Rest controller method signature

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public SomeData getData(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request){
    // do something with Long Id
}
```

Is anything going to break (in Spring maybe, when converting the REST data) if I change the Long argument to String:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public SomeData getData(@PathVariable("id") String id, HttpServletRequest request){
    // Convert id to Long and do something with it
    ...................
}
```

provided I make sure to convert the string to whatever type I need?

Answer (score 0):

It should be okay that do not break the existing client since they can only send you a `Long` string and whatever `Long` string they send you , you are also able to convert it to the `String` java object.

Comment: I am actually doing the opposite, the original method takes Long and I want to change it to String (provided I take care of conversion later).

Comment: yup . I know and did not misunderstood your question.